# Qt images using checkboxes

Tags: qt

I want to add images in Qt and make them work with check boxes. How can I do that?
Can I use the `ischecked()` function for that or should I use signals and slots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ischecked function in order to do that in an if statement.
Please go through the basic concepts of Qt before you start working on it.